# How to loop through MongoDB entries, sum up the entries and present in React front-end

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I'm wanting to loop through different entries in my MongoDB Database, pull out the value/figure from a specific aspect of those entries, sum them all up and present it in my React front-end via props.

To hopefully explain better, here's my code:

My MongoDB schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  creditCard: String,
  personalLoan: String,
  provider: String,
  balance: Number,
  limit: Number,
  monthly: Number,
  interest: Number,
  borrowed: Number
});
```

My Fetch API file:

```
  module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const submitDebts = await SubmitDebt.find({});
  return res.status(200).json(submitDebts);
};
```

Where I want to display the figures pulled from my database:

```
<IndividualDebtSummary balance="£2600" monthly="£430"/>
```

The 'fetch' code in React:

```
 this.state = {
      debts: []
    }

     componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("/api/fetchDebtCards")
        .then((response) => {
          this.setState({ debts: response.data })
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        })
      }
```

This 'summary' component I'm hoping will be where the figures pulled out from my database will be stored, and then presented as props.

To further explain, if for example I had three entries in my database:

- Item 1 - Balance = £1300, Monthly = £110
- Item 2 - Balance = £1200, Monthly = £160
- Item 3 - Balance = £2000, Monthly = £180

The sum of the balances for these three entries would be £4500, and the monthly would be £450.

This would then mean that the props in the component would be as follows:

```
 <IndividualDebtSummary balance="£4500" monthly="£450"/>
```

But obviously rather than hard-coding them, I want it to be dynamic and update with the database. So if another entry was put on, the figure would change etc.

I suspect the most efficient way would be to use the 'fetch' function in my React code, create a variable which loops through the entries and a sum, before rendering it in my return statement.

So as follows:

```
const sumDebts = this.state.debts.map (debt => {

firstFunction = () => {

forEach(debt.balance)......

}

secondFunction = () => {

forEach(debt.monthly)...

}

return (

<IndividualDebtSummary balance={firstFunction} monthly={secondFunction} />

}
```

However, I can't get my head round how best to do this. Can anyone cleverer than me point me in the right direction of how best to do this?

Comment: How does the frontend know when the backend has been updated? This sounds like something for webhooks.

Comment: It’s connected through serverless functions. :-) I’ve just found it to be more efficient and cleaner, far less code. All the functions are working spot on, including storing and retrieving the data, it’s just manipulating it so it does what I want it to do now.. Which I can’t get my head round!

Comment: Since this question is listed in tag "mongodb", please provide the sample JSON example data and expected outcome for the sample input data. I can write in Mongo DB query.

Comment: I'm not sure I need to do a MongoDB query.. I'm getting all of the data I need from my 'fetch' function I think? So it would seem to be a React / JavaScript function.

Comment: Another question, why do you want to use `fetch` when you already use `axios`? Also, do you get all data you need in your `componentDidMount` function and you just have problems displaying the proper data?

Comment: Sorry - think I'm being really unclear here. I don't need fetch, I'm using Axios - just not explained it properly. And yes that's right. I'm actually rendering the database entries already in my webpage.. I'm just wanting to sum up the balance + monthly from those entries, and show them in a separate component. Hope that makes sense. Happy to edit my original question if it's that unclear!